# Conversion of jqcron cron format to support Quartz cron format

Tags: javascript, jquery, cron

I am using jqCron to generate cron expression for scheduling my job. Example cron expression for everyday at 9:30 is  "30 9 * * *"
Quartz supported cron format for same expression is "0 30 9 * * ?"

Is there any js utility available for converting jqCron generated cron to support Quartz formatted cron or vice versa.

[Support for Quartz plugin](https://github.com/arnapou/jqCron/issues/4)

In this example  jqCron js internal method is being overwritten to support Quartz format . Can we do it without overwriting jqCron js like with some js utility function

Thanks

Comment: What is the syntax of the Quartz cron format? I assume the changes aren't as simple as `add a leading zero and use '?' instead of '*' in final field`?

Comment: Quartz format is second Minute Hour DayofMonth Month DayofWeek.

Comment: So it just has an extra leading seconds column and uses `?` instead of `*`? (I assume `?` is the wildcard everywhere and not just in the `DayOfWeek` column?)

Comment: Tricky part is usage of ? in conversion to Quartz Cron format from jqCron. Its not a wild card everywhere.

Comment: So what is the spec? Is there documentation?

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Answer (score 1):

Go through below link. I used this one API and it is quartz compatible.

https://github.com/felixruponen/jquery-cron

Some one can download the source from above Git Repository and include CSS file and jquery-cron-min.js file in their project. Below snippet of code will be good start for anyone.

```
$('#schedulerWidget').cron({
            initial: "0 0/1 * * * ?",
            onChange: function() {
                cronValue = $('#schedulerWidget').cron("value");
                console.log('Cron Updated Value: '+cronValue);
                $("#schedulerWidgetSelctedValue").text(cronValue);
            },
            customValues: {
                "5 Minutes" : "0 0/5 * * * ?"
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I use backoffice conversion before scheduling Quartz jobs with the following tools https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils

and the following helper class

```
public class CronTimeDefinition {

public static final String CRON_SCHEME_MANUAL = "manual";
private boolean            isManual           = false;
private boolean            isCorrect          = false;
private String             unixDefinition;

public CronTimeDefinition(String definition) {

    if (definition.equals(CRON_SCHEME_MANUAL)) {
        isCorrect = true;
        isManual = true;
    } else {
        CronDefinition cronDefinition = CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.UNIX);
        CronValidator oValidator = new CronValidator(cronDefinition);

        if (oValidator.isValid(definition)) {
            unixDefinition = definition;
            isCorrect = true;
            isManual = false;
        }
    }
}

public boolean isManual() {
    return isManual;
}

public static boolean isManual(String crondef) {
    return crondef.contains(CRON_SCHEME_MANUAL);
}

public boolean isCorrect() {
    return isCorrect;
}

public String getUnixDefinition() {
    return unixDefinition;
}

public String getQuartzDefinition() {
    return cronConversion(unixDefinition, CronType.UNIX, CronType.QUARTZ);
}

/**
 * Cron format converter
 *
 * @param a_cronStrin gcron string to convert
 * @param a_from input type
 * @param a_to : output type
 *
 * @return converted format cron
 */
private static String cronConversion(String a_cronString, CronType a_from, CronType a_to) {
    String result = "";

    if ((a_from == CronType.UNIX) && (a_to == CronType.QUARTZ)) {
        String[] cronSplited = a_cronString.split("\\s+");
        if ("*".equals(cronSplited[2])) {
            cronSplited[2] = "?";
        } else if ("*".equals(cronSplited[4])) {
            cronSplited[4] = "?";
        }
        String[] days = cronSplited[4].split("[,-\\-]+");
        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {

            if (StringUtils.isNumeric(days[i])) {
                cronSplited[4] = cronSplited[4].replace(days[i], String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(days[i]) + 1));
                days = cronSplited[4].split("[,-\\-]+");
            }
        }

        // Force 0 for seconds field
        result = "0 " + String.join(" ", cronSplited) + " *";
    } else if ((a_from == CronType.QUARTZ) && (a_to == CronType.UNIX)) {
        result = a_cronString.substring(2, a_cronString.length() - 2).replace("?", "*");
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (isCorrect) {
        if (isManual)
            return "manual";
        else
            return unixDefinition;
    } else {
        return "incorrect definition : " + unixDefinition;
    }
}
```